# macOS - Access app paths in Privacy and Security pane in System Preferences?

Tags: macos, security, big-sur, privacy, command-line

I am on macOS Big Sur 11.4 and have just allowed an app to access the microphone:

[image: privacy pane]

The app's name isn't Electron, but a component of it that provides audio functionalities is built on electron.

As you can see, Electron is a very generic app (or, framework) name and the Privacy and Security pane showing this isn't very helpful as I have no idea (for sure) which app this Electron app belongs to.

I guess the list of authorized apps are is store in a sqlite database stored somewhere in the System or User Library, but I don't know exactly where. If I knew, I could've read the paths of the authorized apps myself.

So my question is, where is this database located, or is there another way to access the paths of the authorized apps?

Update:

I think the database is located in `/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db`, and is readable with Apple-signed `sqlite3`. In the `access` table in `TCC.db`, apps authorized to access the microphone have the `service` attribute of `kTCCServiceListenEvent`, but `Electron` and some other apps shown in the window (see the redacted image above) are not marked to access the microphone, which is weird. Why is that?

Comment: For macOS the application requesting access is Electron, not some subcomponent of it.

Comment: Right-click > Show in Finder?

Comment: @anki no - as the App is shown here as Electron which is not what the user is runnning (another reason not to chose Electron as a way to build apps ;))

Comment: @Redarm OMG I can't believe it's that simple. That is the way Apple intended for users to do it IMO.

Comment: @nohillside It could be an Electron.app inside a larger app bundle, in my case, the Electron.app is an standalone app inside ~/Library/Application Support that works with the main app.

Comment: @mmmmmm Yeah, I definitely prefer using and building native apps. :)